# Reading letters from a custom iPhone keyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, keyboard, puzzle

I'm trying to build an app that is a code breaking puzzle for the user. I've followed sample code on how to add a decimal to the numeric keypad and it works great. I would like to expand this so the whole keyboard is filled with custom images.

Is it possible to have a piece of code that when the user presses on a symbol the iPhone reads it as an "A" for example?

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: Could you link to this (decimal) sample code? I'd love to look it over.

Answer (score 1):

Add to your UITextFieldDelegate (or UITextViewDelegate) :

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
  NSLOG(@"USER PRESS: %@", string);
}
```